# Display the selected items (combobox) other values from a list<>

Tags: c#

I have a comboBox filed from a list thus:

```
locationCcomboBox.DataSource = ReadExcelFile(ExcelFilePath, "some properties"); \\ returns a list of class property.

locationCcomboBox.DisplayMember = "Location";
```

the Class is a simple class:

```
public string chain { get; set; }
public string location { get; set; }
public string postcode { get; set; }
public string phone { get; set; }
```

What I can't get into my head is how when the user selects an option from the combobox is how I select the phone,chain etc to write the correct value out to a text box for each!

## BrainGoneSouth!

Comment: Might be helpful to state what `ReadExcelFile` returns - is it a `List<Class>`?

Comment: Hi Nikki sorry it is on the post but you need to scroll right, but it is returning a List<class>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of your `locationCcomboBox` an then get your class instance by the `SelectedItem` property:

```
//At form load or constructor:
locationCcomboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += locationCcomboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;  

private void locationCcomboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (locationCcomboBox.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        Class myClass = locationCcombo.SelectedItem as Class;

        if (myClass != null)
        {
            //access the members of myClass here
        }
    }
}
```